# How to bypass the signin step when using LiveSDK?

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-sdk

I am writing a Windows Phone application to test another application and want to use skydrive to save screenshots of that application. I am using LiveSDK and each time I deploy the app I have to insert username and password to connect to skydrive. How can I provide my user/pass in the code to avoid the consent and signin page? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you save the token

Comment: You get the token after the consents. I want to avoid the sign in page and consents programmatically.

Comment: No way to get a token w/o signing in. That's the point.

Comment: And my question is how to sign in and get the token without requesting any user input? (write a code to do so with a default username and password)

Answer (score 0):

When initializing an instance of LiveConnectClient, add "wl.offline_access" to the list of scopes. With offline access, the users of your app do not have to sign in and give consent every time they use the app. Please follow the link below for more information on scopes and permissions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243646.aspx